# Average integral of a function over a ball

Tags: calculus, integration

How to show that the average integral of a continuous function over a ball converges to the value at the center as the radius goes to zero , i.e,
[image]

Comment: What measure is $S$? Are we assuming it's Lebesgue or are we working on more general measure spaces?

Comment: @forgottenarrow Yes its lesbegue measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the closed ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ is compact, so $f$ restricted to $B(x,\epsilon)$ is uniformly continuous. This means that for any $\delta > 0$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that,

$$\sup_{y \in B(x,2\epsilon)} \left|f(x) - f(y)\right| < \delta.$$

Or in other words, whenever $y\in \partial B(x,\epsilon)$, we have
$$ f(x)-\delta < f(y) < f(x) + \delta. $$

Integrating w.r.t. $dS(y)$ and noting $|\partial B(x,\epsilon)| = \int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}\,dS(y)$ gives us

$$\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} (f(x) - \delta)\,dS(y) < \int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(y)\,dS(y) < \int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}(f(x)+\delta)\,dS(y)$$

which is same as

$$ (f(x) - \delta)|\partial B(x,\epsilon)| < \int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(y)\,dS(y) < (f(x) + \delta)|\partial B(x,\epsilon)|. $$

Dividing by $|\partial B(x,\epsilon)|$ yields,

$$f(x) - \delta < \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,\epsilon)|}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(y)\,dS(y) < f(x) + \delta.$$

Since $\epsilon\to 0$ as $\delta\to 0$, we get

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{|\partial B(x,\epsilon)|}\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)} f(y)\,dS(y) = f(x).$$

Just multiply by $-1$ to get your answer.

Comment: I don't know how to get the average integral symbol without using packages.